# Film set for Lost Girl 4.3 same as Hemlock Grove season 2?

Tags: real-location, lost-girl, hemlock-grove

The exterior and interior of the house shown in *Lost Girl* season 4, episode 3 ("Lovers Apart") looks nearly identical to Olivia Godfrey's house in *Hemlock Grove*, season 2.

Was the same location used?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they both used [Eaton Hall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaton_Hall_(King_City)#Filming_location), a large stately house in Ontario, Canada as one of their primary filming locations. Note the distinctive fireplaces and stained glass windows.

**Hemlock Grove**
[image]

**Lost Girl**
[image]

Eaton Hall has been used as a set for various Canadian-made productions such as "Death Weekend", "Mrs. Winterbourne" and the final scene of the film "A History of Violence".

On top of that, both shows share over [40 common cast and crew](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt1429449,tt2309295) including a [prop designer](http://fraserpaterson.com/resume.html), [Art Designer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3767701/) and [Set Dresser](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3767701/).